# Specific file on AWS is CORS blocked when using domtoimage

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-to-image package.

I have an upload service where users can upload images on a AWS S3 storage solution. The uploaded file gets stored in a div, this way the user can create a sort of collage.

[image]

```
toImage() {
  domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('shelve'))
    .then(blob => {
      saveAs(blob, 'my-node.png');
    });
}
```

The user can then export the shelve to a image for their own usage. For some reason some pictures on AWS return a CORS error, other images work fine:

[image]

AWS bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "***",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "***",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::***",
                "arn:aws:s3:::***/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

CORS policy:

```
[
  {
      "AllowedHeaders": [
          "*"
      ],
      "AllowedMethods": [
          "PUT",
          "POST",
          "GET",
          "DELETE"
      ],
      "AllowedOrigins": [
          "http://localhost:3000"
      ],
      "ExposeHeaders": []
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick google fu let me to https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image/issues/315

```
   let options = { "cacheBust":true }
   domtoimage.toJpeg(node, options)
```